# Azure, Webapp - how to make web access public

Tags: azure, web-applications

I currently have a VM running everything as I would like with a Python app running live on a port, that I am able to access it privately via the "visualize web" button. However, the link is only accessible if I am logged into my azure account. Can anyone please point in the correct direction for getting the app accessible to anyone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to allow inbound network to the port your web app is using (80 / 443):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal